# Google sheets scripts question on drawing object. Looking for a way to tell which script is assigned to which drawing object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google spreadsheet with four drawings that have scripts assigned. One of them is a delete image. Trying to use this button to first draw checkboxes next to the items which could possibly be deleted and then later delete the rows which have boxes checked.

Is there a way to check the action assigned to a drawing prior to changing it. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you have any code or screenshots you could share showing the desired behavior. From what I understand I think this should be possible but I am not sure what you mean by `Is there a way to check the action assigned to a drawing prior to changing it.`

Comment: I was trying to change the script assigned to a Drawing object via program control.  I wanted to find out the script previously assigned to the object prior to changing it.

Comment: Ah, you mean you had a macro assigned to a drawing and you want to get the current function and change it with another function/macro?

Comment: Correct. Google reassigns the indices in the drawing objects array every time there are changes to the array. As far as I can tell, there is no good way to track within a script which drawing object has a particular script assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to identify Drawings and the attached function with Apps Script

```js
function getMacros(){
  const file = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sheet = file.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const drawings = sheet.getDrawings()

  drawings.forEach(d => {
    Logger.log(d.getOnAction()) // Gets name of function
    Logger.log(d.getContainerInfo().getAnchorColumn())
    Logger.log(d.getContainerInfo().getAnchorRow())
    Logger.log(d.getContainerInfo().getOffsetX())
    Logger.log(d.getContainerInfo().getOffsetY())
    Logger.log(d.getZIndex())
  })
}
```

You said that the order of the buttons changed each time the script was called, however this was not what I found. Though it is likely to change if you modify the drawings.

You can use [`getOnAction()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing#getOnAction()) to specifically get the function attached to a drawing. It will return the name of the function.

You can use the methods related to [`ContainerInfo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/container-info), which will give you anchor columns and rows and X and Y offsets, which you could also use to identify drawings. Finally the [`getZIndex()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing#getZIndex()) method might come in handy, even if you aren't layering the drawings, to use as an ID of sorts. You can `setZIndex()` too.

To keep track of the numbers you associate with different drawings, you could use the [`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) so that you can save information within the script.

For example. Once you have your drawings set up, you can run a variation of the above script to get all the numbers associated with the different drawings and keep them with the `PropertiesService`. Then you have a sort of "fingerprint" with which to identify them in the future.

#### References

- [`Drawing`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing)
- [`Sheet.getDrawings()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdrawings)
- [`getOnAction()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing#getOnAction())
- [`getContainerInfo()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing#getContainerInfo())
- [`ContainerInfo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/container-info)
- [`getZIndex()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing#getZIndex())
- [`PropertiesService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Comment: Thank you. that works. Not sure why I was not seeing the getOnAction method before.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'beforechange' nor 'oldvalue' feature.

You may consider to watch all the assigned actions upon `onLoad` or `onEdit` to track the change indirectly.